# Setup mail server on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: email, ubuntu-10.04, sendmail, squirrelmail

I'm trying to setup a mail server on Ubuntu 10.04.

I followed this instructions:

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/postfix.html#postfix-troubleshooting
```

when I'm testing the connection through telnet, I'm getting the following results:

```
Trying 149.154.153.11...
Connected to mail.broodds.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 tanko-20590-i5 ESMTP (Debian/GNU)
ehlo mail.broodds.com
250-mail.broodds.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
```

Is this a good result, because in the tutorial this is different:

```
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN
250 8BITMIME
```

Using `Sendmail` I can send out mail, but how can I check weather do I got an email.

I also installed the Squirrelmail, but when I type something in the login I get the following error:

```
ERROR
Error connecting to IMAP server: localhost.
111 : Connection refused
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So which IMAP server did you install and configure? Postfix is only a SMTP server.

You see different results after EHLO because you didn't configure SMTP AUTH.

If your mail was delivered or not (probably not as you didn't complete the SMTP dialog) can be seen under `/var/log/mail.log`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I installed postfix, how can I setup the SMTP Authentication? And add new email addresses?

Comment: Aren't that new questions?! But fortunately Wietse documented this: http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html and even in your referenced link you can find the answer.